# Reading pipe in C with libaio

Tags: c, linux, asynchronous, pipe, epoll

I am trying to create a web server in C that uses epoll for multiplexing IO. I was trying to make it capable of generating PHP pages.

What I did: For each connection I read the path, created unnamed pipe, called forked then I redirected the output of the child process to the pipe and used `execvp("php", (char *const *) argv);`. In the parent process I added the pipe to epoll with EPOLLIN and then I wait for it in the main loop. When it was signaled I used `io_prep_pread` from libaio to read asynchronously, and then when the read part is finished I would send the buffer to the client.

The problem is the right result is outputted like 5-10% of the time. Is the logic I presented correct or should I wait for the child process to send `SIGCHLD` and then start reading the pipe?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please show the actual code as a [minimal verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). English language is imprecise so it is necessary to show the code to make things clear.

Comment: Fork and popen is a heavyweight operation for handling one connection.

Comment: You don't need to use AIO, just set the pipe to non-blocking mode if you don't want to block in `read()`.

Comment: @Barmar Setting it to non blocking seems to have solved the problem. Now I have to investigate why this is actually happening but for the moment that seems to be the solution. Thank you!